# Deleting a dynamically allocated array from a function that initiates it C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm writing a program in C++ that has to use dynamically allocated arrays from various structures (in separate files). A lot of times, I need to initiate these arrays inside of a function. Usually after initiating them, I write data to the array of a structure, or even an array inside of an array of structures, and then use the data later on. Therefore I don't use delete inside of the function.

For example, here is one of the structures that I use, a student structure:

```
struct Student {
    int id; // student ID
    char gradeOption; // either G or P
    double totalScore;
    std::string studentName;
    int* rawScores = NULL; // array that holds raw scores for a student
    // if no scores are entered for a specific ID, we check for NULL
    // we can then set the scores to 0
    std::string* finalGrade; // final grade given in course
};
```

And here is the function to input raw scores.

```
// input raw scores for each id
void inputRawScores(int gradedArtifacts, int id, Student* student) {
    student[id].rawScores = new int[gradedArtifacts];
    for(int i = 0; i < gradedArtifacts; i++) {
        std::cin >> student[id].rawScores[i];
    }
}
```

In my driver file, students also gets initialized with a value. Shown here:

```
 Student* students = new Student[numOfStudents]; // array of students
```

The problem is is that I use these raw scores, and the array of students for calculations in a separate file, and use them for output in other files, and in other methods. How would I go about deleting any of these?

Also I realize that using `delete` will delete the structure and the pointers inside of the structure, but not the objects that the pointers point to. So I'm assuming this ties back into the first question and I can't just issue a `delete` at the end of my program.

Edit: I'm sorry, as many others have pointed out I should have stated the restraints that I have on the project. I'm not allowed to uses: classes, vectors, functions inside of structs (like constructors, destructors).

Comment: You can just issue a `delete []` after deleteing all other dynamically allocated objects held in `Student`.

Comment: The simple solution is not to use pointers and `new` at all.

Comment: Why not using smart pointers? Or you can use vector, or map if you need to do some kind of linking between the pointers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ unfortunately, in my driver file, after issuing delete[] student, memcheck still reports that it is a memory leak inside of the function.

Comment: @sop I'm unfortunately not allowed to use smart pointers, or vectors, or much of anything besides dynamically allocated arrays and structs. :(

Comment: If you have silly artificial requirements, you should state so clearly in your question.

Comment: You cannot create your own smart pointer eater?

Comment: You cannot use `std::vector`, smart pointers or classes ? you are doing C my friend. Welcome to a world of hurt, where even the most basic ownership problem becomes subject to never ending debates.

Comment: Don't you know a struct essentially is nothing but a class in C++?

Comment: The basic problem is not that you have to practically write your code in C, but that your teacher, or whoever gave you that constraints, is mixing C++ with C by letting you use `std::string` (which is a C++ class). In C you would use C-Strings (`char*`). I often find that this mix-and-match often confuses students because they don't know when to use what, and more than often use C-style programming in C++ programs when they really shouldn't later on.

Comment: @moooeeeep Yes, but my professor explicitly stated we could not use member functions, constructors, or destructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your newly posted constraints, I think you could just implement a deletion-function to traverse through the `Student` array and do manual cleanup.

First, we create a function that deletes the dynamic objects of **one** single student. Note that we could have used `Student&`as the parameter type, but given the information in your question I am not sure if you have learned references yet, or if you are allowed to use them. So we stick with the pointer:

```
void cleanupStudent(Student* student) {
    delete[] student->rawScores;
    delete student->finalGrade;

    // EDIT: Setting pointers back to NULL after deletion provides
    // some improved safety and is good practice.
    student->rawScores = NULL;
    student->finalGrade = NULL;
}
```

After that we create a function that allows you to delete the complete `Student` array by looping through all the items in the array and calling the cleanup function:

```
void deleteStudents(Student* students, int studentCount) {
    for(int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++) {
        cleanupStudent(&students[i]);
    }

    delete[] students;
}
```

Here, please note the ampersand-symbol (`&students[i]`) which we require to get a pointer to the object (which is required as a parameter to the cleanup function). After that, the student array itself is deleted.

You can call these functions like this:

```
int numOfStudents = 16;
Student* students = new Student[numOfStudents];
deleteStudents(students, numOfStudents);
```

Or with a single student:

```
Student* student = new Student;
cleanupStudent(student);
delete student;
```

As you might have noticed we sometimes use `delete` and sometimes `delete[]`. The first one just deallocates memory that has been allocated with `new`. The latter does the same thing to memory that has been allocated with `new[]`. This is very important to get right, otherwise you will get runtime errors. Also, make always sure that **EVERY** pointer in your struct is initialized wih `NULL` (C) or `nullptr` (C++).

Since it seems that you are just learning C/C++ it is crucial to mention that the above code is very unsafe, and you could get into real problems if e.g. the `studentCount` is not matching the actual number of items in the array. But for now I guess you wouldn't know (or aren't allowed) to do better.

EDIT: I noticed that your `finalGrade` member is of type `std::string*`. Is there a reason for this to be a pointer? Because if you just want to store a string, you can just do a `std::string`, no reason there to be a pointer. Please don't confuse a C-String of type `char*` with a STL string `std::string`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! And the only reason I made finalGrade a string was because if the grading option is set to pass/not pass, I have to output the finalGrade as "NP". Since each student has a different final grade based on which set of cutpoints are being used, I thought I would use a pointer so I can allocate memory to create an array of final grades to store for output.

Comment: Fair enough, but make sure that if you ever do a `new std::string[]` you also have to `delete[]` the grades in the cleanup function. Currently we only do a regular `delete`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do that.

Your system is badly designed, your `struct` should be a `class` and internally handle the `rawScores` memory - using a `std::vector` would be the easiest part, but even if you use regular pointers, the key is that the information about how many there are, and where they are stored, should be tracked in a `class`.

In other words, the `student` structure should keep track of HOW MANY elements there are, and allocate/deallocate the memory as needed. It should not be done in the function `inputRawScores` - that function may well call the function for `setNumRawScores` and call the function for `setRawScore(n, value)`, but not allocate memory in the reader function. That belongs as a member function in the `student` structure. Then introduce a destructor method for your `student`, that is responsible for deallocating the memory.

Of course, using `std::vector` will "hide" all this from you, and you just have to set the size (or use `push_back`).

Answer (score 0):

It would be very tedious to effectively delete everything you hve allocated using new in this case as you are passing pointers to other modules/functions.

You have two options over here:-

1. Either replace those dynamic arrays ( rawscores/finalGrade ) with corresponding vectors.
2. You can use smart pointers ( I think auto_ptr would suffice if you are not using containers ) to take care of memory mangement.

EDIT:-

**One main issue you have to handle if you are creating raw student pointer is of ownership**. Let's say you have allocated memory to Student* and then you are passing this object to several modules/functions. You need to take into account that you don't call delete when your pointer is still in use in some other module. Also it should also not call delete when it's already deleted in some module. That's why I pointed you to two options...

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is obsolete since the owner of this questions specified some constraints that do not allow constructors/destructors.**

As far as I unterstand your question, you do not know how to delete the actual dynamically allocated `rawScores` and `finalGrad` objects in your `Student` object, right? If so, the answer is quite simple, you just use a Destructor:

```
struct Student {
    int id; // student ID
    char gradeOption; // either G or P
    double totalScore;
    std::string studentName;
    int* rawScores = nullptr;
    std::string* finalGrade = nullptr;

    // Disable copy and move assignment
    Student& operator=(const Student& rhs) = delete;
    Student& operator=(Student&& rhs) = delete;

    // Disable copy and move construction
    Student(const Student& rhs) = delete;
    Student(Student&& rhs) = delete;

    Student() {
        // Initialize members.
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Student() {
       delete[] rawScores;
       delete finalGrade;
   }
};
```

As soon as you deallocate a `Student` object using the `delete` operator:

```
Student* students = new Student[numOfStudents];
delete[] students; // <-- deallocation
```

The destructor is called for each object, which in turn will delete the dynamically allocated objects inside.

You don't have to bother if the pointers are `NULL` or not, calling `delete` on a pointer that is `NULL` is valid. Also, please initialize ALL pointers initially with `nullptr` when constructing the object (as shown above).

As long as you are not mixing runtimes accross different EXE/DLL boundaries you can `delete` the `Student` array from anywhere in your program, not matter in which file you allocate/deallocate it.

I hope this answers your question. If not, please be more specific about the problem you have.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, you should disable copy/move semantics if you are doing it this way (or implement them). But disabling them would practically pin you to dynamic allocation of the `Student` struct and give you less flexibility with most of the STL containers. Otherwise you could also use an `std::vector` instead of dynamically allocated arrays as pointed out in the other anwers.

Comment: Very good explanation. But you missed one essential thing in this. How would you handle ownership issues for Student pointer if its being passed to several modules/functions.

Comment: Now you need a copy constructor and an assignment operator.

Comment: @ravi That's true, ownership is not covered here. For this smart pointer would be best I guess. This answer does not take this into account.

Comment: @juanchopanza Usually I prefer these anyway, along with move construction/assignment, as the dynamically allocated scores and finalGrade objects themselves have to be copied in copy ctor/assignment, not just the pointer. I think it's good practice to do so, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: The point is that if you don't provide them, or don't make the class non-copyable and non-assignable, it is badly broken.